# I am trying to hit a certain local MPESA Payment API but am getting an error

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5

I am trying to get a response from MPESA payment API using laravel but I am getting an error . My code is as below

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MPESA_AUTH extends Controller
{
    public function Authorize(){

        $url = 'https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials';
        $CONSUMER_KEY= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $CONSUMER_SECRET= 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $credentials = base64_encode($CONSUMER_KEY,$CONSUMER_SECRET);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic '.$credentials)); //setting a custom header
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

        $curl_json=json_decode($curl_response);
        return $curl_json;
    }
}
```

The error am getting is as below
[image]

Comment: Change / revoke your key immediately! We can still see it in the edit history. (It's also still present in your screenshot.)

Comment: its on test sandbox no issues

Comment: _"no issues"_ Don't assume that. If one of the endpoints allows me to read data back, it could reveal other sensitive information from hits you've previously posted. Change the key.

Comment: Okay i have changed the credentials thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Base controller uses Illuminate\Routing\Controller trait which has an 'authorize()' function. Your function declaration is clashing with it.
Change your controller method name to anything else(other than 'authorize') and you should be good to go

Comment: I am getting this error after changing the name "Class App\Http\Controllers\MPESA\MPESA_AUTH does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different function name in place of "Authorize". This is because "authorize" in controllers is a preserved name used in the parent class Controller.